# Java concurrent queue for broadcast?

Tags: java

I have a bunch of producer threads adding to a `BlockingQueue` and one worker thread taking objects. Now I want to extend this so two worker threads are taking objects, but doing different work on the objects. Here's the twist: *I want an object that has been put on the queue to be worked on by **both** of the receiving threads*.

If I keep using BlockingQueue, the two threads will compete for the objects, and only one of the worker threads will get the object.

So I'm looking for something similar to BlockingQueue, but with broadcast behaviour.

The application: The producer threads are actually creating performance measurements, and one of the workers is writing the measurements to a file, while the other worker is aggregating statistics.

I'm using Java 6.

So does such a mechanism exist? In Java SE? Elsewhere? Or do I need to code my own?

I'm looking for solutions with a small footprint - I'd prefer not to install some framework to do this.

Comment: No other suggestions except write my own code for broadcasting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option: have *three* blocking queues. Your main producer puts items into a "broadcast" queue. You then have a consumer of *that* queue which consumes each item, putting it into both of the other queues, each of which is serviced by a single consumer:

```
                                   Q2
                                  ---- Real Consumer 1
          Q1                     /
Producer ---- Broadcast Consumer
                                 \
                                  ---- Real Consumer 2
                                   Q3
```

Alternatively, you could give two blocking queues to the producer, and just get it to put the items it produces into both. That's less elegant, but slightly simpler overall :)

Comment: Agreed - that's definitely a possibility, and fairly simple to code. I'm just thinking that Java must have this kind of functionality built-in.

Comment: @TueWennerberg: Not that I'm aware of. You'd really want two interfaces, one for the producer and one for the consumer - then you could create a "BroadcastQueue" which implements the part the producer needs, and allows as many pass-throughs as you want to be added to it. But I don't know of anything built into the framework for that.

Comment: Guess there's no standard java component for this, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Haskell's [Chan](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html) and its [dupChan](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html#v:dupChan) function would do exactly what you want. I'm really tempted to port it to Java at some point...

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet idea is beautiful in its simplicity. Other than that you can use the disruptor pattern, which is faster and addresses exactly this problem. I can give you a code example with [CoralQueue](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/06/multicasting-with-coralqueue-through-a-splitter/), which is an implementation of the disruptor pattern done by Coral Blocks, with which I am affiliated. It provides a data structure called `Splitter` that accepts a single producer offering messages and accepts multiple consumers polling messages, in a way that *all messages are delivered to each and every consumer*.

```
package com.coralblocks.coralqueue.sample.splitter;

import com.coralblocks.coralqueue.splitter.AtomicSplitter;
import com.coralblocks.coralqueue.splitter.Splitter;
import com.coralblocks.coralqueue.util.Builder;

public class Basics {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERS = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Builder<StringBuilder> builder =  new Builder<StringBuilder>() {
            @Override
            public StringBuilder newInstance() {
                return new StringBuilder(1024);
            }
        };

        final Splitter<StringBuilder> splitter = new AtomicSplitter<StringBuilder>(1024, builder, NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERS);

        Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            private final StringBuilder getStringBuilder() {

                StringBuilder sb;

                while((sb = splitter.nextToDispatch()) == null) {
                    // splitter can be full if the size of the splitter
                    // is small and/or the consumer is too slow

                    // busy spin (you can also use a wait strategy instead)
                }
                return sb;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                StringBuilder sb;

                while(true) { // the main loop of the thread

                    // (...) do whatever you have to do here...

                    // and whenever you want to send a message to
                    // the other thread you can just do:
                    sb = getStringBuilder();
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    sb.append("Hello!");
                    splitter.flush();

                    // you can also send in batches to increase throughput:
                    sb = getStringBuilder();
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    sb.append("Hi!");

                    sb = getStringBuilder();
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    sb.append("Hi again!");

                    splitter.flush(); // dispatch the two messages above...
                }
            }
        }, "Producer");

        final Thread[] consumers = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERS];

        for(int i = 0; i < consumers.length; i++) {

            final int index = i;

            consumers[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (true) { // the main loop of the thread

                        // (...) do whatever you have to do here...

                        // and whenever you want to check if the producer
                        // has sent a message you just do:

                        long avail;
                        while((avail = splitter.availableToPoll(index)) == 0) {
                            // splitter can be empty!
                            // busy spin (you can also use a wait strategy instead)
                        }

                        for(int i = 0; i < avail; i++) {

                            StringBuilder sb = splitter.poll(index);

                            // (...) do whatever you want to do with the data
                            // just don't call toString() to create garbage...
                            // copy byte-by-byte instead...
                        }

                        splitter.donePolling(index);
                    }
                }
            }, "Consumer" + index);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < consumers.length; i++) {
            consumers[i].start();
        }

        producer.start();
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of CoralQueue.