# Is there a data structure similar to a queue that can do multicast to different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, multicast

I would like to send the same message to a set of threads in a way that each thread gets all the messages that I am adding to the queue. It is like a broadcasting queue. Is there a data structure like that, preferably in Java?

Comment: where the running threads would be?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891284/java-concurrent-queue-for-broadcast?  Might you be able to adapt https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/am/BroadcastQueue.java?

Answer (score 2):

Stock your data in a static [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) , and let your threads access to it.

Comment: This does not work. Once a thread gets a message the other thread will not get the same message.

Comment: @JohnPristine don't poll , just peek :)

Comment: if( queue.peek() != null ) grab( queue.poll() );

Comment: I don't think a ConcurrentLinkedQueue will work... Once you poll() the queue, other consumers will miss that message.

Comment: i've  said just **peek()** your data. and poll it under your specific critarias .

Comment: @Mifmif but if I send two messages to the queue, how does that work? I have to eventually poll so that the next message comes along. Someone will have to poll, and once they poll how can I guarantee that all threads got the message?

Comment: @Mifmif, I think you're missing the point.  JohnPristine wants each new datum to be automatically removed from the "queue" as soon as every registered thread has received it, but not before.  May also want a method that waits until there is a message that the calling thread has not yet seen.

Comment: @JohnPristine it seems that you want each thread work on messages without waiting for poll() from someone .if this is the case, then you need more then ConcurrentLinkedQueue, may be something similar to a Pub/Sub system where each Thread would have it's messages list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the disruptor pattern for that. If you want something similar to a data-structure you can check the `Splitter` from [CoralQueue](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/06/multicasting-with-coralqueue-through-a-splitter/). It allows a producer to send messages to multiple consumers in a way that each consumer receives and processes each and every message.

Below is a simple example:

```
package com.coralblocks.coralqueue.sample.splitter;

import com.coralblocks.coralqueue.splitter.AtomicSplitter;
import com.coralblocks.coralqueue.splitter.Splitter;
import com.coralblocks.coralqueue.util.Builder;

public class Basics {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERS = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Builder<StringBuilder> builder =  new Builder<StringBuilder>() {
            @Override
            public StringBuilder newInstance() {
                return new StringBuilder(1024);
            }
        };

        final Splitter<StringBuilder> splitter = new AtomicSplitter<StringBuilder>(1024, builder, NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERS);

        Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            private final StringBuilder getStringBuilder() {

                StringBuilder sb;

                while((sb = splitter.nextToDispatch()) == null) {
                    // splitter can be full if the size of the splitter
                    // is small and/or the consumer is too slow

                    // busy spin (you can also use a wait strategy instead)
                }
                return sb;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                StringBuilder sb;

                while(true) { // the main loop of the thread

                    // (...) do whatever you have to do here...

                    // and whenever you want to send a message to
                    // the other thread you can just do:
                    sb = getStringBuilder();
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    sb.append("Hello!");
                    splitter.flush();

                    // you can also send in batches to increase throughput:
                    sb = getStringBuilder();
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    sb.append("Hi!");

                    sb = getStringBuilder();
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    sb.append("Hi again!");

                    splitter.flush(); // dispatch the two messages above...
                }
            }
        }, "Producer");

        final Thread[] consumers = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERS];

        for(int i = 0; i < consumers.length; i++) {

            final int index = i;

            consumers[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (true) { // the main loop of the thread

                        // (...) do whatever you have to do here...

                        // and whenever you want to check if the producer
                        // has sent a message you just do:

                        long avail;
                        while((avail = splitter.availableToPoll(index)) == 0) {
                            // splitter can be empty!
                            // busy spin (you can also use a wait strategy instead)
                        }

                        for(int i = 0; i < avail; i++) {

                            StringBuilder sb = splitter.poll(index);

                            // (...) do whatever you want to do with the data
                            // just don't call toString() to create garbage...
                            // copy byte-by-byte instead...
                        }

                        splitter.donePolling(index);
                    }
                }
            }, "Consumer" + index);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < consumers.length; i++) {
            consumers[i].start();
        }

        producer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread to pickup a message from queue and then send it to all thread by saving the message in local queue for each thread.